# python / python matplotlib ignore/exclude files have less than 20 data points and count data points and includes it in the graph

Tags: python, python-2.7

We prepare a following python scripts (python 2.7) to make histograms.

histogram.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
mpl.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sys.argv[1]  # Define input name
sys.argv[2]  # Define output name
sys.argv[3]  # Define title

# Open the file name called "input_file"

input_file=sys.argv[1]

inp = open (input_file,"r")

x = []

for line in inp.readlines():

        x.append(float(line))

# the histogram of the data

        n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, 50, normed=False, facecolor='gray')

        plt.xlabel('Differences')

        plt.ylabel('Frequency')

        title=sys.argv[3]

        plt.title(title)

        plt.grid(True)

        save_file=sys.argv[2]

        plt.savefig(save_file+".png")

        plt.clf()

inp.close()
```

example: input

```
1
2
3
3
3
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
1
```

The script will do the following

python histogram.py input ${output_file_name}.png ${title_name}

May we know if there is any way in Python to filter out input files which have less than twenty data points (all the input formats are one data point per line)?

Also may we know if there is any way to count the number of data points and include the counting into the histograms (such as in titles or legends "n=?") ?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly you just need a minor adjustment to your code:

```
lines = inp.readlines()
if len(lines) >= 20:
    for line in lines:
        # do stuff
```

Comment: Yes just remove any input which line number is smaller than 20.  Wow super easy solution!

Comment: Also may we know if there is any way to count the number of data points and include the counting into the histograms (such as in titles or legends "n=?") ? Thanks!

Comment: @Chubaka `len(lines)` is the number of lines, so in your case it is the same as the number of datapoints. You could just store this number in a variable, e.g. `numpoints = len(lines)`. I don't know much about matplotlib but I am sure it is trivial to include this number in your figures after reading the docs.